# In R can I combine colums when importing data with read.table?

Tags: r, read.table

I have two different files that use slightly different names for data references. In file1 it looks like ND-1234, while file2 it appears as ND 1234. The problem is that the data is whitespace separated, so I the identifier in file2 will create 2 columns. I know I can import file2 to a data.frame and then manipulate it to combine those columns, but it is a fairly large  file, so I would prefer to perform this on import.

So, I have two questions:

1) Can I, on import, force file2 to combine columns 1 & 2 to create data that looks like ND-1234? (Note that this would also require inserting a '-' in between the data from the two columns)

2) If this is possible, is faster to do it this way or to use post processing like I would have before?

Here are some examples of the data:

```
FILE1:
1       2 3 4 5 6
-----------------
ND-1234 1 A C T G
ND-412  1 T C A A

FILE2:
1  2    3    4
----------------
ND 1234 1.23 xyz 
ND 412  0.23 abc

WHAT I WANT is to import file2 to look like this:
1       2    3
----------------
ND-1234 1.23 xyz
ND-412  0.23 abc
```

Comment: Can you please show a few lines of both files

Comment: Sorry, accidentally, hit add too early above. The files look like this.
`FILE1: ND-1234 ABCD 12 xyz`
`FILE2: ND 1234 1.23 2 4 efg`
What I want is this:
`FILE2: ND-1234 1.23 2 4 efg`

Comment: can you add this IN your question, and not in comment? The formatting does not help...

Comment: I don't think that's possible directly when importing the data. You can, however, paste the values together

Comment: @Barranka Can you convert your comment into an answer, so I can tag this question as answered.

Comment: @caffein Done. I think you can use `paste()` to get what you need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that's possible directly when importing the data. You can, however, paste the values together.

Example:

```
# Sample:
df <- data.frame(
  var1 = c('ND','ND'),
  var2 = c(1234,412),
  var3 = c(1.23, 0.23),
  var4 = c('xyz','abc'),
  stringsAsFactors=F
)

# Paste the values together, and store them in a new column:
df$var5 <- paste(df$var1, df$var2, sep='-')

# Get the desired columns:
df[,c('var5','var2','var3','var4')]
##     var5 var2 var3 var4
##1 ND-1234 1234 1.23  xyz
##2  ND-412  412 0.23  abc
```

---

Another possible solution (but maybe it's overkill) is to use the [`sqldf`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html) package:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select var1 || '-' || cast(var2 as int) as new_var, var3, var4 from df")
##  new_var var3 var4
##1 ND-1234 1.23  xyz
##2  ND-412 0.23  abc
```

The `||` operator is used to concatenate strings (`sqldf` uses SQLite as a "backend"). I cast `var2` as an integer to prevent the result from having decimal places.